# Need help referencing image correctly in minikube private registry

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, docker-registry

I'm trying to deploy a custom pod on minikube and I'm getting the following message regardless of my twicks:

```
Failed to load logs: container "my-pod" in pod "my-pod-766c646c85-nbv4c" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled
Reason: BadRequest (400)
```

I did all sorts of experiments based on https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/ and https://number1.co.za/minikube-deploy-a-container-using-a-private-image-registry/ without success.
I ended up trying to use `minikube image load myimage:latest` and reference it in the container spec as:

```
  ...
  containers:
    - name: my-pod
      image: myimage:latest
      ports:
        - name: my-pod
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
   ...
```

Should/can I use `minikube image`?
If so, should I use the full image name `docker.io/library/myimage:latest` or just the image suffix `myimage:latest`?
Is there anything else I need to do to make minikube locate the image?
Is there a way to get the logs of the bad request itself to see what is going on (I don't see anything in the api server logs)?

I also see the following error in the minikube system:

```
Failed to load logs: container "registry-creds" in pod "registry-creds-6b884645cf-gkgph" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating
Reason: BadRequest (400)
```

Thanks!
Amos

Comment: When you use `minikube load image ...` do you have to use registry credentials? do you have to use `docker-env` attributes `eval $(minikube docker-env)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [imagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy) to `IfNotPresent`. Changing that will tell kubernetes to not pull the image if it does not need to.

```yaml
  ...
  containers:
    - name: my-pod
      image: myimage:latest
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      ports:
        - name: my-pod
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
   ...
```

A quirk of kubernetes is that if you specify an image with the `latest` tag as you have here, it will default to using `imagePullPolicy=Always`, which is why you are seeing this error.

[More on how kubernetes decides the default image pull policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#imagepullpolicy-defaulting)

If you need your image to always be pulled in production, consider using [helm](https://helm.sh/docs/) to template your kubernetes yaml configuration.